# Correct way to boxing bool[] into object[] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I want to find the best approach for converting `bool[]` into `object[]` in C# .NET 4.0.
Now I have this variables:

```
object[] objectArray  = new object [] { true, false, true };
string[] stringArray  = new string[]  { "true", "false", "true" };
bool[]   boolArray    = new bool[]    { true, false, true };
```

All are created fine. For 'clear types', suc as `bool` and `object`, [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) works fine (`object o = true;`). But in this case I can do conversion only from a string array to an object array, but not from a boolean array:

```
objectArray = stringArray; // OK 
objectArray = boolArray; // WRONG Cannot implicitly convert bool[] to object[]
```

Also, in some methods I am sending a list of object arrays. As in previous case, I can do this (conversion) for string, but not for a boolean array:

```
List<object[]> testList;
testList = new List<object[]>() { objectArray }; // OK
testList = new List<object[]>() { stringArray }; // OK
testList = new List<object[]>() { boolArray };   // WRONG - I can not add bool[] into object[]
```

From some methods, I have a boolean array with many items inside ... and the last method, after all calculations, returns an object array as a result (sometimes it must return other types and I don't want to split it into multiple methods).

Whereas, I can not use `return_object_array = boolean_array`. What is the best method for doing this? Is looping over all values in a boolean array and storing it into an object array the fastest way?

**What is the best / fastest / most correct approach to do this?**
*Note: This method is writen under .NET 4.0, but if you know a better solution for .NET 4.5 I'd like to know it.*

Comment: `boolaray.Select(x => (object)x).ToList();`

Comment: I think this is an X/Y problem - Why do you want to convert an array of booleans to an array of objects in the first place? Why is the method returning arrays of different types? Why are you working with `List<object[]>`?

Comment: I can not use generic types because some methods are created implementing interface (not my interface :)). But I know that better is use generic.

Comment: The reason why it works with `string` and not `bool` is that `string` is a reference type, and _covariance_ features in .NET work only with reference type. For arrays, a `string[]` is also an `object[]` because of .NET 1-style **array covariance**. This covariance is "dangerous" because an array is not read-only; .NET will perform a type-check each time you try to write a new reference to an array of reference types! With the constructor of `List<>` that takes in an `IEnumerable<>`, it works by covariance introduced **in generics** since .NET 4 (in 2010, C# 4: `interface IEnumerable<out T>`).

Comment: @Matt A simple oversight. You didn't have to write that long comment for stating obvious :)

Comment: @L.B.: .ToList(); creates an error, but .ToArray(); does the right thing. Better? ;-)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to box each value, right? That's as simple as:

```
object[] objectArray = boolArray.Select(b => (object) b).ToArray();
```

Or even:

```
object[] objectArray = boolArray.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

(As `Cast` *will* perform boxing/unboxing operations.)

Or slightly more efficiently in terms of knowing the correct size to start with:

```
object[] objectArray = Array.ConvertAll(boolArray, b => (object) b);
```

Alternatively, change your APIs to *not* require an `object[]` to start with. Consider using generic methods/types instead.

EDIT: To avoid the boxing each time, you can easily write your own extension class similar to the framework one nmclean showed:

```
public static class BooleanBoxExtensions
{
    private static readonly object BoxedTrue = true;
    private static readonly object BoxedFalse = false;

    public static object BoxCheaply(this bool value)
    {
        return value ? BoxedTrue : BoxedFalse;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
object[] objectArray = Array.ConvertAll(boolArray, b => b.BoxCheaply());
```

Or:

```
object[] objectArray = boolArray.Select(BooleanBoxExtensions.BoxCheaply)
                                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Out of interest, are you using 'b' for the lambda because the value is a bool?

Comment: @Bobby you can use any letter or word for the lambda, but some people (including me and Jon Skeet) prefer to use a letter that is related to the variable's name. So, for a `boolArray` I would use `b` and for an `objectArray` I'd use `o`.

Comment: I often go even further and use a proper name. Many people have only a vague understanding of lambdas, and a chain of them can really inspire terror, which can be somewhat reduced by seeing a name. For simple cases like an array of bools, though, the added value is probably much smaller.

Comment: Or if object is required, at least cache the boxes [as the framework does](http://dotnetinside.com/en/framework/v4.0.30319/WindowsBase/BooleanBoxes).

Comment: @nmclean: Is there any public Framework method equivalent to `BooleanBoxes.Box`?

Comment: @supercat: Not that I'm aware of, but I've included the code (written from scratch rather than copying!) and made it an extension method.

Answer (score 11):

`Cast<T>` method performs boxing.

```
var castedValues = boolArray.Cast<object>();
objectArray = castedValues.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
bool[] boolArray = { true, false, true };

var objArray = Array.ConvertAll(boolArray, x => (object)x);
```